# Skyrim crashes after bethesda logo. No mods installed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

So, my Skyrim crashes just after bethesda intro. Tried to disable intro and it crashed after few seconds of showing skyrim logo.

I have no mods installed. I had but because it stopped working, i deleted everything. i manually deleted my old saves and .ini files. (load orders etc.) and everything from steamapp. I have tried to change audio setting to every possible option but none of them works. 
I have reinstalled 3 times now

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

specs

Windows 7

gtx 780 4gb with 3x 1920x1080 screens

AMD Phenom II x6 3.2 Ghz

asus Formula IV motherboard

12 gb 2000mhz ddr3

Comment: Just to clarify. You tried to disable the intro sequence and this started happening? The game was working before?

Comment: If you check your load order (Data files in the launcher iirc), what do you see in there?

Comment: No i tried, to disable intro sequence after crash's started, and it only moved crash so i could watch skyrim logo in main menu for 2 seconds, but not seeing any buttons.
 and my load order has 
Skyrim.esm
Update.esm
nothing else

Comment: It sounds like the game is failing to load and hangs. If reinstalling doesn't fix it then I'm not sure. You could try a clean clean install. Uninstall, restart computer, install. See where that gets you.

Comment: have you verified the integrity of your game cache after installing?

Comment: Thank you. Rapitor! "a clean clean install" did the trick!

Comment: If you've solved it, feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: Clean the registry before installing anything and after uninstalling something. CCleaner, Registry Mechanic, ect.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to go into steam, then go to The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim, then click local files and click on the button that says verify game integrity. This should replace any missing files. If this doesn't work there might be a problem with Skyrim not being assigned enough RAM or something along those lines.

To fix the problem with RAM, you will have to download a program called [SKSE](http://skse.silverlock.org). This is really easy to install, and once it is installed launch skyrim through skse_loader.exe in your skyrim root folder (see under).

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\skse_loader.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to lower your audio format to 16 bit (CD quality) under:
Control Panel > Sound > Select sound card > Properties > Advanced > Default Format.

This worked for me.

Comment: Why does this fix the problem?

Comment: Do you have any backing to this fix? Any proof that it was a factor in the error?

Comment: Although the poster of this answer has not provided any source it is a genuine fix, at least for some issues, and many people (myself included) found that this worked. Here's one of many suggestions of the fix (see the last post by *NeuroStryker*): http://www.overclock.net/t/1165416/skyrim-sound-issues